# Xamarin.ios : Xamarin.essentials for MediaPicker.capturePhotoAsync rotate image in 90 degree

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.Essentials Framework to capture photo form Camera . In below code MeidaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() used

```
-(void)catchphoto()
{
var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
if (photo == null)
{

      return;
}
await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);

}


async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
{
if(photo == null)
{
   PhotoPath = null;
   return;
}

var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())

using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))

await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

PhotoPath = newFile;

UIImage image =  UIImage.FromFile(PhotoPath);
```

//this image is rotated image.

```
if(image != null)
{

if(image.Orientation == UIImageOrientation.Up)
    image = new UIImage(image.CGImage, 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Right);
}

}
```

Orientation of the Images working fine in case of portrait mode, but when we capture photo in landscape mode above solution is not works .
Can anyone knows solution for it ? or any other method to avoid rotation of photo.

Comment: Is anyone used Xamarin.Essentials's MediaPicker for capturing photos in Xamarin.ios ? I am still facing rotating image issue . can anyone help?

Comment: we tried it but skip it because of this orientation issue

Comment: okay, [jfversluis comments](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-1015305704) share his suggestions. The community also gave some solution. You can follow up this thread: [MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync - Orientation of photo rotated 90 degrees](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue on GitHub: [[Bug] MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync - Orientation of photo rotated 90 degrees](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514). That may because exif or other metadata is missing when capturing the photo using MediaPicker. And as [jfversluis commented](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-1004314212), they won't be able to fix this for Essentials anymore.

However, [glintpursuit comments](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-874148026) propose a workaround that should work. That is to implement your own MediaPicker class. To use the MediaPicker, you can simply start with creating a new MediaPicker instance and invoke **CapturePhotoAsync** method. And glintpursuit's custom MediaPicker works on my end.

Hope it helps.